# Replace title column in post list with post meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have created custom post type called booking. It have a meta `booking_first_name`, `booking_last_name`, `booking_email`, `booking_phone`, `booking_phone_contact`. Currently, I succeeded displaying email, phone and mobile phone.

[image]

However, i want to display my post title as `booking_first_name` + `booking_last_name`. How could I do that?

Here is my current syntax :

```
<?php
/**
 * Register custom admin field
 */
add_filter('manage_booking_posts_columns', 'booking_table_head');
function booking_table_head( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['booking_email']          = 'Email';
    $defaults['booking_contact_phone']  = 'Contact Phone';
    $defaults['booking_mobile_phone']   = 'Mobile Phone';
    return $defaults;
}

/**
 * Fill custom field value
 */
add_action('manage_booking_posts_custom_column', 'booking_table_content', 10, 2);
function booking_table_content( $column_name, $post_id ) {

  switch ($column_name) {
    case 'title':
      $first_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'booking_first_name', true );
      $last_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'booking_last_name', true );
      echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
      break;

    case 'booking_email':
      $email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'booking_email', true );
      echo $email;
      break;

    case 'booking_contact_phone':
      $contact_phone = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'booking_phone', true );
      echo $contact_phone;
      break;

    case 'booking_mobile_phone':
      $mobile_phone = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'booking_phone_mobile', true );
      echo $mobile_phone;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `the_title` filter.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'my_meta_on_title',10, 2);
function my_meta_on_title($title, $id) {
  if('booking' == get_post_type($id)) {
      return get_post_meta( $id, 'booking_first_name', true ).' '.get_post_meta( $id, 'booking_last_name', true );
   }
  else {
      return $title;
  }
}
```